# Problems while loading CSS tied to an EJS page while using res.redirect()

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, ejs

So I'm using express with ejs where I've this as my base route
`router.get("/", productsData.getProducts);`
where productsData is from my controllers page and this is the code there

```
exports.getProducts = (req, res, next) => {
    res.render("shop/index", { pageTitle: "Shop", path: "/" });
};
```

[network tab in the developer tools show the css files werent loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRaPk.png)
On checking it I saw net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on the request for the css files.

If I reload the page it works fine and the css are loaded. This is the code for the CSS import.
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />`
The only thing that goes wrong is when It redirects here

```
exports.postAddProduct = (req, res, next) => {
    const product = new Product(req.body.title);
    product.save();
    res.redirect("/");
};
```

Can anyone tell whats going wrong, is it with something with res.redirect() or something else?

Comment: Looks like an issue of paths. Where is your css file? Also what are the URLs being shown in the browser in both cases?

Comment: The css files are located in the public/css folder. I've also added ```app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));```

Comment: Also this isse only happens when they are redirected to '/' path by res.redirect('/'), and resolves when I refresh the page manually.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the code was good, I was saving the form uploads in a file in the directory same as my code while using nodemon, which was watching the whole code. So everytime I submitted the form, it restarted the server because of which this issue occurred.

Comment: ```nodemon app.js --ignore *.json``` fixes this